# How to create thread for 10 ids, run 6 methods parallel in java using multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading, multitasking

I have 10 Ids in List, and 6 methods.I need to every id in 6 methods.

Example:

//passsing 1st id in all 6 methods, these 6 methods should run parallel

```
getBook1(1);
getBook2(1);
getBook3(1);
getBook4(1);
getBook5(1);
getBook6(1);
```

// passing 2nd id in all 6 methods

```
getBook1(2);
getBook2(2);
getBook3(2);
getBook4(2);
getBook5(2);
getBook6(2);
    .
    .
    .
```

// passing 10th id in all 6 methods

```
getBook1(10);
getBook2(10);
getBook3(10);
getBook4(10);
getBook5(10);
getBook6(10);
```

When i pass the 2nd id in all 6 methods, in parallel 1 id methods should also run in parallel.
Like for all these 10 ids for 6 methods should run parallel in java.
Please help me with solution.

Thanks for your response. please check the updated code below.

```
public class TestClass {
DataSource ds = null;
Connection mysqlcon = null;
PreparedStatement mysqlstmt = null;
ResultSet mysqlrs=null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    TestClass tc = new TestClass();
    List<String> idsList  = tc.getIpadds();
    ExecutorService executorService =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(idsList .size());
    Method[] methods = TestClass.class.getMethods();

    for (String id : idsList ) {
        callbookMethod(executorService,id,methods);
    }

}

private List<String> getIpadds() {
    List<String> ipadds = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
            // MySql Dash Board Connection
            ds = MyDataSourceFactory.getDashBoardMySQLDataSource();
            mysqlcon = ds.getConnection();
            String sql="SELECT DISTINCT IPADD FROM atm_master_copy_3";
            mysqlstmt = mysqlcon.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet mysqlrs =mysqlstmt.executeQuery();

            while(mysqlrs.next()) {
                ipadds.add(mysqlrs.getString(1));
            }

        }catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if(mysqlcon != null) {
                    try {
                        mysqlcon.close();
                    }catch(SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mysqlcon = null;
                }
            }
    return ipadds;
}

public static void callbookMethod (ExecutorService executorService,final String id, final Method[] methods){
    final TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (Method method : methods) {
                try {
                    String methodName  = method.getName();
                    if (methodName.startsWith("update")) {
                            method.invoke(testClass,id);
                   }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

public void updateCMaster(String id)  {
     System.out.println("updateCMaster");

}
public void updateFMaster(String id) {
    // Do Something
    System.out.println("updateFMaster");
}
public void updateASMaster(int id) {
    // Do Something
    System.out.println("updateASMaster");
}
```

}

i am geting 250 ids in list.

Comment: So you want to loop over all id's and start 6 threads for each one!

Comment: yes, when i pass 2nd id in all 6 methods, in parallel 6 methods should also run with 1st id. @AMA

Comment: So the total number of active threads will be list.size * 6 ? 
in your case list size is 10  so the total will be 60 !!!

Comment: Yes, you are right. can you please help me with the solution @AMA

Answer (score 0):

Here you go this will do what you asked for, but this is not a good idea since you will kill your machine because if the list size is big:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestClass {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

        int[] idsList = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        ExecutorService executorService =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(idsList.length);
        Method[] methods = TestClass.class.getMethods();

        for (int id : idsList) {
            callbookMethod(executorService,id,methods);
        }

    }

    public static void callbookMethod (ExecutorService executorService,int id, Method[] methods){
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (Method method : methods) {
                    try {
                        String methodName  = method.getName();
                        if (methodName.startsWith("getBook")) {
                            method. invoke(testClass,id);
                        }
//                        method.invoke(id);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void getBook1(int id)  {
        // Do Something
        System.out.println("Book 1:");
    }
    public void getBook2(int id) {
        // Do Something
        System.out.println("Book 2:");
    }
    public void getBook3(int id) {
        // Do Something
        System.out.println("Book 3:");
    }
    public void getBook4(int id) {
        // Do Something
        System.out.println("Book 4:");
    }
    public void getBook5(int id) {
        // Do Something
        System.out.println("Book 5:");
    }
    public void getBook6(int id) {
        // Do Something
        System.out.println("Book 6:");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry i just mentioned example method names in my question, but have different method names.  if (methodName.startsWith("getBook")) what i have to do here.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.in.TestClass$1.run(TestClass.java:76)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)           getting this exception

Comment: Parameter type for this method updateASMaster is int and you sending the id as String that's way check updateASMaster method to accept String 


    public void updateASMaster(String id) {
        // Do Something
        System.out.println("updateASMaster"+id);
    }

Comment: or you can do this 
##



    public static void callbookMethod(ExecutorService executorService, final String id, final Method[] methods) {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                testClass.updateCMaster(id);
                testClass.updateFMaster(id);
                testClass.updateASMaster(id);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: No need of for loop inside run () ah @AMA

Comment: The for loop useful if you have a lot of methods you need to call so you don't have to call them one by one, read about reflection.

Comment: This is your code output: Book 1:===4
Book 2:===4
Book 3:===4
Book 1:===3
Book 2:===3
Book 3:===3
Book 1:===1
Book 2:===1
Book 3:===1
Book 1:===5
Book 1:===2
Book 2:===2
Book 3:===2
Book 2:===5
Book 3:===5,

Comment: But my requirement is other Book 1:===1
Book 3:===3
Book 2:===1
Book 3:===1
Book 1:===3
Book 3:===3
Book 3:===3
Book 2:===3
Book 2:===1
Book 3:===3
Book 1:===1
Book 1:===5
Book 2:===5
Book 3:===3
Book 3:===5
Book 3:===1
Book 1:===2
Book 3:===3
Book 2:===2
Book 3:===1
Book 3:===3
Book 1:===1
Book 3:===2
Book 1:===4
Book 3:===3
Book 2:===4
Book 3:===1
Book 2:===1
Book 3:===4
Book 3:===3

Comment: this is my requirement

Comment: When i pass the 2nd id in all 6 methods, in parallel 1 id methods should also run in parallel. This condition is not working. please help me with the correct solution. @AMA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209494/discussion-between-asha-and-ama).